# Sending form data through AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var _csrfToken = $('meta[name=token]').attr('content');
var link = $('meta[name=url]').attr('content');


$('#upload_form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var designation = $('#position').val();
    var category = $('#category').val();
    var azimaData = {
        name: title,
        designation: designation,
        category: category,
        _token: _csrfToken

    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link + '/@dashboard@/galleryImage/add_image',
        data: azimaData,
        //use contentType, processData for sure.
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(msg) {

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });

});
```

I am trying to send form data through ajax. For now I'm just trying to see if I can access these data in my controller.

```
public function addGalleryImageAction(Request $request)
{
    return $request->name;
}
```

But when I click on submit button nothing happens.. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What do you get on your request response? If you are using chrome click F12, navigate to Network and see your ajax request. It should show you an error or any response

Comment: check `print_r( $request);` and see what is there? check your browser console.

Comment: There's no code in your `success` or `error` handlers, so nothing would appear to happen. What are you expecting? Have you checked the request is working in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm trying to access those data in server, which I'm not being able to

Comment: That's my point - how do you know? There's no code in either of the handler to receive what you send back

Comment: `success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function() {
         console.log("error occur");
        }` add this, run your code and check browser console.

Comment: it is giving 'TokenMismatchException' error.. But csrf_token is working fine for other ajax requests...